# What advantage does cash-settled futures have over spot?

Tags: futures, trading, market

For example with bitcoin there is both the spot market and a [cash-settled quarterly futures market](https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/a3401595e1734084959c61491bc0dbe3).

As a buyer when would I want to buy quarterly futures instead of just buying on the spot market?

Spot offers the advantage of actually owning the underlying and holding a long position in perpetuity. With quarterly futures I get none of the utility of owning bitcoin and I also have to roll my position every 3 months. So why would someone buy futures instead of spot?

Comment: The possibility of going long *or* short, the implicit leverage, the ease of short term trading are the main advantages. The inconvenience of rolling the position and the danger of a disconnect between spot and futures (think of what is going on now in the London nickel futures market) are the main drawbacks.

Comment: You do not have to warehouse the underlying.

Comment: You do not have risk of fraud/hacking

Answer (score 3):

Futures are derivative instruments that are traded for many different purposes, by many different types of accounts. Limiting the discussion to your specific example though, the primary advantage futures have over owning physical bitcoin is **leverage**.

If you buy one bitcoin in the physical market your cash outlay is the full price of that bitcoin, say USD 44,000. Ignoring any of the fair value parameters that would affect the no-arbitrage futures price, lets say the price of a bitcoin future is also USD 44,000. To open a position that futures contract your cash outlay is limited to the exchange mandated initial margin, let's say 10%. In the futures transaction your initial cash outlay is only USD 4,400.

As long as initial margin + any additional incremental margin (variation margin) sums to less than 100% of the position's mark to market value, the futures trade is implicitly levered.